# urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object>,'Connection to api.twitter.com timed out. (connect tim eout=60)')

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am looking to retrieve some tweets using some search terms. After collection of around 25,000 tweets, it started producing timeout error. FYI, I am using Academic Research account and Twitter API v1.

I want to understand the cause of the error so that I can retrieve more tweets.

Following is my scraping script:

```
def scrape(words, orig_text):
    # search for tweets between 2015 and 2018
    start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
    end = datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 31)

    db          = pd.DataFrame(columns=['text', 'hashtags', 'search tag', 'id'])
    tweets      = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=words, lang="en", tweet_mode='extended').items(25000)
    list_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets]

    for i, tweet in enumerate(list_tweets):
        tweet_id = tweet.id
        hashtags = tweet.entities['hashtags']
```

Following is how I make connection:

```
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```

Following is the traceback for the error:

```
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 1013                                                                                                                        
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 1014                                                                                                                        
Rate limit reached. Sleeping for: 1014                                                                                                                        
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                            
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 175, in _new_conn                                    
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw                                                                                                     
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection                        
    raise err                                                                                                                                                 
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection                        
    sock.connect(sa)                                                                                                                                          
socket.timeout: timed out                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                              
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                              
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                            
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 710, in urlopen                                  
    chunked=chunked,                                                                                                                                          
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request                            
    self._validate_conn(conn)                                                                                                                                 
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn                          
    conn.connect()                                                                                                                                            
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 358, in connect                                      
    conn = self._new_conn()                                                                                                                                   
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 182, in _new_conn                                    
    % (self.host, self.timeout),                                                                                                                              
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f051a69efd0>, 'Connection to api.twitter.com timed out. (connect tim
eout=60)')

Traceback (most recent call last):                                             
  File "twitter_api.py", line 67, in <module>                                                                                                                 
    main(search_words)                                                         
  File "twitter_api.py", line 52, in main                                      
    scrape(search_words[i], orig_text)                                         
  File "twitter_api.py", line 20, in scrape                                    
    list_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets]                                                                                                                 
  File "twitter_api.py", line 20, in <listcomp>                                                                                                               
    list_tweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets]                                                                                                                 
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 86, in __next__
    return self.next()                                                         
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 286, in next
    self.current_page = next(self.page_iterator)                                                                                                              
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 86, in __next__
    return self.next()                                                         
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/cursor.py", line 167, in next
    data = self.method(max_id=self.max_id, parser=RawParser(), *self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 33, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)                                             
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)                                             
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 1272, in search_tweets
    ), q=q, **kwargs                                                           
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 222, in request
    raise TweepyException(f'Failed to send request: {e}').with_traceback(sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 219, in request
    timeout=self.timeout, auth=auth, proxies=self.proxy                                                                                                       
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)                                      
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)                                        
  File "/home/kgarg8/anaconda3/envs/uda_pytorch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 507, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)                                                                                                                  
tweepy.errors.TweepyException: Failed to send request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /1.1/search/tweet
s.json?q=%22faith%22+OR+%23faith&max_id=1508152899637063689&lang=en&tweet_mode=extended (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection obj
ect at 0x7f051a69efd0>, 'Connection to api.twitter.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)'))
```

Comment: "Academic Research account" -> v2 API. You're hitting the v1.1 recent search API endpoint (`tweepy.API` uses v1.1). You're actually never even using the `start` and `end` values you've defined. Have  you checked on the dates of the Tweets you've saved? They will be within the past 7 days. The error you're seeing is a network error rather than an error from the Twitter API itself (`"connect timeout"`)

Comment: Everything you said is correct but how I can resolve this network error?